# Tomcat8 error on deploy

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java-7, tomcat8

When i deploy my application on Tomcat 8 Manager, i have this error message :

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /cnafc but context failed to start

In catalina.out, i have this error message (and a lot more) :

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [/cnafc]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.deployInternal(HTMLManagerServlet.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:208)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/cnafc] Context cannot be started.
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext.startInternal(FailedContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 48 more
```

I am on Debian GNU Linux 7.10 (Wheezy). The application is built with jdk 1.7.0_11, same as installed on my debian.
The application is working with the same Tomcat / Java on Windows but can't figure out where is the problem with a linux environnement.

If you need more information to help me solve the problem, i have what you want ! :)

PS : JDK on my debian was installed with apt-get openjdk-7-.... but the repo is not available for Tomcat8 so i installed it from official apache (got all the shell script but still got windows .bat file in it)

Comment: Dig in the log just a bit more - it is cut off before the "real" issue is shown.  Tomcat has a very verbose error log so there should be more errors under what you show.  You don't have to paste the whole thing here - keep going down from what you show and look for a "Caused by" or something like that.

Comment: You probably horribly broke one of the `context.xml` files. Check `conf/context.xml` for XML syntax errors as well as your own application's descriptor(s). Also, read all the log files. Because many things are happening at similar times, the errors aren't always together in the log  file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I already checked all the logs, but there is no other message than the one i showed. Context.xml in the conf directory is fine for XML Syntax, demo applications run correctly and tomcat runs too, the problem appear when i try to start my new application, that worked previously on Tomcat 6

Here is the "Caused by" :
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/cnafc] Context cannot be started